# UIImageView in tableview cell subclass not working as IBOutlet

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uiimageview

I have a UITableViewCell subclass, nothing fancy. I added several labels and an UIImageView. All outlets are connected to the Table View Cell (the view) - not the File's Owner. If I'd attach them to the File's Owner, loads of errors about not being key-value compliant and attaching them to Table View Cell actually solved that problem. I can address the labels correctly.

However, one of my IBOutlets is now not properly connected: an UIImageView. The IBOutlet is set up, and what works for the labels doesn't do the trick for the image view. Here's some code:

```
[[cell imageView] initWithImage:thumbnail];
[self.view addSubview:[cell imageView]];
```

Imagine thumbnail is an UIImage, which is not nil. cell.imageView is nil neither. The top line doesn't show the image in the right place (where I set it up in the xib), although the bottom line actually adds the image to the screen - not in the right place.

So what's going on here? How can I get the outlet right, either by adding it correctly to the File's Owner (without key-value compliance complaints) or by connecting it correctly through the Table View Cell. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Kind regards,

Reinder

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
[[cell imageView] initWithImage:thumbnail];
```

sounds quite strange. If the imageView has been already initialized, e.g. by the nib, then there is no need to re-initialize again (with undesired results, as init must be called once in the life of an object). Instead if the imageView instance has not been alloc-init yet, then [cell imageView] will be nil and the initWithImage: call will have no effect at all.

So you say that cell.imageView is not nil, so your init methodWithImage: method will probably change the frame of the image view and this explains why it has been moved somewhere else than your xib (probably it has been placed in the cell view origin). Don't forget the when an image is loaded from a xib the initWithCoder: method is called instead.

What you can do as a walk around is this code (not tested) which replaces the existing cell with the new cell:

```
CGRect oldFrame = cell.imageView.frame;
UIImageView *newImageView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:thumbnail] autorelease];
newImageView.frame=oldFrame;
[self.view addSubview:newImageView];
cell.imageView=newImageView;
```

Of course this solution is not elegant and it would be better if you could fix your KVC issues. The reason of why you get those errors is not clear to me, I should see the code and the xib. It don't understand what you mean with "doesn't do the trick". There shouldn't be tricks, unless you will be hit by bugs like this.